# Magento 2 Add CMS/phtml block bottom before product_list_toolbar and after product_list (Between)

Tags: layout, blocks, xml, magento2.2.2

I am not able to add a cms block in category page.

XML: `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.filter.content.bottom" template="my_module::test.phtml"/>`

what I have tried:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.filter.content.bottom" template="Amasty_Shopby::layer/test.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <!-- addedJust before product_list_toolbar does not work!?--><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.filter.content.bottom" template="My_Module::test.phtml"/> 
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </block>
      ......
```

Next tried to add to `product_list_toolbar`:

```
<referenceContainer name="product_list_toolbar">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.filter.content.bottom" template="My_Module::test.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Yet without luck.

If add within content it works but it will be added either before the list at the very top or a the bottom after the tool bar which is not what I need.

What I need can be see in the screen shoot bellow!

[image]

Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Is you find this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your static block/PHTML file in `list.phtml` file which is located at `Magento_Catalog\templates\product` folder.

Find `<?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>` code at below in `list.phtml` line no **119** in default file and add code above this line like below:

**For static block**

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

**Note:** Replace static **block_identifier** with your **static block identifier**.

**For PHTML file**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("my_module::test.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: I thought of that already but that's not ideal I can't overwrite this file in my custom module as it's also being overwritten in the custom theme.